# can i use input type = file in my single page application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, single-page-application

I'm writing my first single page application and have a requirement by where the user is going to need to upload documents and/or images.

Is this a show stopper for using a spa or is there a work around?

I seem to be able to find very little on this on the net so I'm wondering if this requirement would mean creating a normal mvc site?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to upload files using ajax, so no show stopper there.  you might need a controller to accept the file though, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Check out this tutorial on an ajax upload
http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

or you can check out uploadify, i think that does file upload via ajax too